# I want to check Ajax form submit progress message

Tags: ajax, forms, submit, cypress

There will be a  message displayed"Ajax Request is Processing!" while  one ajax form submit is is clicked and the process is in progress.
once the process is completed we will get another message "Form submitted Successfully!"
I am trying to check the progress message using Cypress.io but assertion always able get the final text only.

```
describe('Verify that Fe male is selected', function () {
    it('clicks the link "type"', function () {
        cy.visit('https://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/ajax-form-submit-demo.html')
        cy.get('#title').type("MyTest Name").should('have.value', 'MyTest Name')
        cy.get('#description').type("MyTest Description")
        cy.get('#btn-submit').click().should('not.exist')
        cy.get('#submit-control').should('have.text',"Ajax Request is Processing!")
        cy.get('#submit-control').should('have.text',"Form submited Successfully!")
    })
})
```

But this always fails showing assertion error 
CypressError: Timed out retrying: expected '' to have text 'Ajax Request is Processing!', but the text was 'Form submited Successfully!'

How can we check this temporary message displayed while submit action is in progress.

Image attached

Comment: this might be caused by the submit request being too fast, where cypress might do the DOM check for `Ajax Request is Processing` right after it was already replaced with `Form submited Successfully`. I haven't tested this, but possibly the only solution would be to introduce artificial latency for this kind of tests. That's what we do.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use contains:

cy.contains("Ajax Request is Processing!")
   cy.contains("Form submited Successfully!")